# SSL certificates execution in the JDK upgrade from 1.8.0_51 to 1.8.0_202

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, certificate

I am utilizing JDK version 1.8.0_51. Over here, I encountered the following error, while fetching the content via WebClient:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <*.*.*>
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.checkURLSpoofing(HttpsClient.java:653) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:577) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
```

However, when I upgrade the JDK version to 1.8.0_202, the problem gets rectified.

When I place both the versions in debug mode to understand the library code, I see the peer certificates created in both the flows are different.

Can someone guide me why is 1.8.0_51 version causing the issue?

Comment: Are you using oracle jdk or open jdk? where did you download it from?

Comment: I am using oracle jdk. I downloaded from here - https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html.

Comment: #1 what is you os? #2 Could you verify if cacerts file exist on `/../jdk/jre/lib/security/` in the default **jdk 1.8.0_51** folder? #3 If exist, check its size and/or compare with your other jdk?

Comment: #1 Issue reproducible in both Mac and Linux

Comment: Is that possible to show me the code? And the website you are trying to access?

Comment: Sorry, its of my workplace, and hence confidential.

Comment: #2 Yes, cacerts file exists in the path - `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security folder`.

Comment: #3 Size of cacerts in jdk 1.8.0_51 - 100K, Size of cacerts in jdk 1.8.0_202 - 104K. Command used `du -sh *`.

Comment: To give details w.r.t. the content being queried - It is hosted at the site, let's take a hypothetical example - `impact.software.com`, with certificate `*.software.com`. The content is served via a cache - akamai. The issue is that 1.8.0_51 has a certificate of akamai, while 1.8.0_202 has a certificate of `*.software.com`. That's why, 1.8.0_51 doesn't work, but 1.8.0_202 works.

Comment: **It's probably SNI.** There have several times been bugs in JSSE about providing SNI, and while I don't remember 8u51 to 8u202 specifically and am not going to go through that many bugfix lists, there could well be one (or more!) in there. And many modern servers, especially CDNs like akamai, require SNI to serve the correct cert. Try running with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl` to see if/when ClientHello includes `Extension server_name`, or (less convenient) use an external capture like wireshark.  @JRichardsz: 'hostname wrong' CANNOT be caused by the truststore.